# Call function and replace arguments correctly

Tags: javascript, function, variables, ecmascript-6, graphql

I have a function with an argument that I want to call inside of another function but I am getting errors. Not sure why the string is being added instead of the value I need.

My Code:

```
const firstFunc = (res) => `
mutation{
    createTable(input: {
      name: "${res}.name"
      color: ${res}.color
    }) 
    }
  }`;
```

I want to call this function inside another function:

```
arr.forEach((d) => {
    console.log(firstFunc("d.data.data.table"));
});
```

This `console.log` is returning:

```
mutation{
    createTable(input: {
      name: "d.data.data.table.name"
      color: d.data.data.table.color
    }) 
    }
  }
```

If I do:

```
arr.forEach((d) => {
    console.log(firstFunc(d.data.data.table));
});
```

This is returning:

```
mutation{
    createTable(input: {
      name: "[object Object].name"
      color: [object Object].color
    }) 
    }
  }
```

Expected result:

```
mutation{
    createTable(input: {
      name: "Test Name"
      color: blue
    }) 
    }
  }
```

How do I get my expected result?

Comment: Don't quote `result.data.data.table`. That makes it a string, not an object with `name` and `color` properties.

Comment: Why aren't you using `d` in the `forEach()`?

Comment: @Barmar sorry, I forgot to add that

Comment: `${res}.name` should be `${res.name}`

Comment: What is `result.data.data.table`? You didn't add that to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't quote the variable `d.data.data.table`. And put the property you want to access inside `${}`.

```
const firstFunc = (res) => `
mutation{
    createTable(input: {
      name: "${res.name}"
      color: ${res.color}
    }) 
    }
  }`;

arr.forEach((d) => {
    console.log(firstFunc(d.data.data.table));
});
```